# How to build Java project from SVN checkout (Encog library)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, classpath, program-entry-point

I am trying to install the Encog library through SVN checkout:

`svn checkout http://encog-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ encog-java-read-only`

However when I import the projects through Eclipse into my workspace, and CTRL+F11 any main method, I get for example `Error: Could not find or load main class org.encog.examples.neural.predict.sunspot.PredictSunspot`.

I have tried to implement the advice of a few SO threads regarding this error message but the advice hasn't worked.

This error will persist even with a simple `HelloWorld.java` that I create within this imported project.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your build path settings are not correct.
Check the project properties settings for the project.